# ACID violation in Postgres 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, concurrency, except, acid

I am using a Postgres DB to implement a scheduling of jobs for a large number of computers/processes. To make the story short, every job has its id, all scheduling is implemented with three tabes: all jobs, currently running jobs, and already completed jobs.

The key functionality of the scheduling is to (1) request a job and (2) inform DB about a completed job. Requesting a job takes any id from the job list, which is not in the running table and not in the completed table:

```
insert into piper.jobs_running
select x.fid from ( 
  SELECT fid FROM piper.jobs
  except 
  select fid from piper.jobs_running
  except 
  select fid from piper.jobs_completed
 ) as x limit 1
returning(fid)
```

Completing the job removes it from the running list and inserts it into the completed list. Since it is not concurrency-specific I ommit the SQL commands (it takes something from tens of minutes to a couple of hours to finish a job.)

It came as a nasty surpirse to me, that two processes runing exactly the same query above (pretty much requesting the job at the same time) may get the same job id (fid). The only possible explanation that I am comming up is that Postgres is not rely ACID conform. Comments?

**Additional information:** I set the transactions to be serializable (in *postgresql.conf* `set default_transaction_isolation = 'serializable'`). Now the DBMS fails the transactions in case the isolation is not fullfilled. is it possible to force Postgres to restart them automatically?

Comment: I don't see why what ACID property would prevent concurrent statements to return the same fid. The fid is "generated" using the select statement, and the select statement will return whatever is visible to the current session. Two concurrent selects will simply return the same fids because they don't see the uncommitted inserts from the "other" session. Using a select statement to generate "new" ids is **always** a bad choice. Your statement is just a `select max(..)` in disguise which will never work properly precisely because of the ACID characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you rephrase the explanation, so it is visible that the isolation of the ACID properties is not violated? If I run two insert statements one after the other then I'd get two different ids. If I run two inserts at the same time, it should be visible as if they are running one after the other (which is not the case here)

Comment: If you run them at the same time, the will ***not*** see the effects of the other insert. If you run them one after the other with autocommit turned off, you basically get the same behaviour: Run the first insert, don't commit, run the select of that insert from a second session and you'll see. As long as the insert has not been committed no other session is allowed to see those values, hence the other sessions retrieves the same information as the first session. This is how transactions work: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: Again I am very grateful for the explanation and the pointer to the tutorial on transactions in postgres. One may run 100 above inserts at the same time but ACID guarantees that I see them as if they were run in some specific order sequentially (which order is completely the same to me). My statement is that they do not look to me as if they are run seequentially, therefore ACID is violated. Reflecting what you said: on commit some inserts must fail and the whole query must be restarted.

Comment: Your understanding of ACID is wrong. It is **not** violated here. One transaction will **never**, ever, under no circumstances see *uncommitted* data from another session. And therefor the `select` statement will never see new rows that are inserted concurrently.

Comment: From wikipedia: Isolation
Main article: Isolation (database systems)

The isolation property ensures that the concurrent execution of transactions result in a system state that would be obtained if transactions were executed serially, i.e. one after the other. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). Or do you mean any other way one may understand isolation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18037/discussion-between-arthur-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: That statement is only true if you use the "serializable" isolation level.

Comment: Read the manual on transaction isolation and concurrency.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres for solution to your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Specific issues with the query

PostgreSQL defaults to `READ COMMITTED` isolation, and it looks like you're not using anything different. In `READ COMMITTED` each statement gets its own snapshot. It cannot see uncommitted changes from other transactions; it's as if they simply haven't happened.

Now, imagine you run this simultaneously in three sessions, on a setup with three entries in `jobs`, zero in `jobs_running` and zero in `jobs_completed`:

```
insert into piper.jobs_running
select x.fid from ( 
  SELECT fid FROM piper.jobs
  except 
  select fid from piper.jobs_running
  except 
  select fid from piper.jobs_completed
 ) as x limit 1
returning(fid)
```

Each run will select the three jobs in `jobs`. Because their snapshots were all taken before any of them committed a change, or even created the uncommitted row, *all of them will find zero rows in `jobs_running` and `jobs_completed`.

So they all claim a job. Probably *the same job*, because even though there's no `ORDER BY`, the scan order will be the same.

### Locking

Row locking crosses transnational boundaries, and lets you communicate between transactions to enforce ordering. So you might think this would solve your problem, but it won't.

If you take a `FOR UPDATE` lock on the `row` entry, so the row is locked exclusively, the lock is held until the transaction commits or rolls back. So you'd think that then the next transaction would get a different row, or if it tried to get the same row it'd wait for the lock to release, see that there was now an entry in `jobs_running`, and skip the row. You'd be wrong.

What'll happen is that you'll lock all rows. One transaction will successfully get the locks on all rows. The other transactions, which will do the same index or sequential scan, will generally try to lock the rows in the same order, get stuck on the first lock attempt, and wait for the first transaction to roll back or commit. If you're unlucky, they might start locking different sets of rows and deadlock against each other instead, causing a deadlock abort, but usually you're just getting no useful concurrency.

Worse though, the first transaction picks one of the rows it locked, inserts a row into `jobs_running` and commits, releasing the locks. Another transaction is then able to continue, and locks all the rows.... but *it doesn't get a new snapshot of the database state* (the snapshot gets taken at statement start), so *it can't see that you inserted a row into `jobs_running`. Thus, it grabs the same job, inserts a row for that job into `jobs_running`, and commits.

### Condition re-checks

PostgreSQL has a quirky feature not included in most databases where, if a transaction blocks on a lock, it re-checks that the selected row still matches the lock condition when it gets the lock after the first transaction commits.

That's why the example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres works - it relies on qualifier re-checks in `WHERE` clauses after reclaiming a lock.

The use of locking forces everything to run serially, so in practice you might as well have a single connection doing the work.

### Isolation, ACID, and reality

Transaction isolation in PostgreSQL is not the perfect ideal where transactions run concurrently, but their effects are the same as if they were executed serially.

The only real world database that would deliver perfect isolation would be one that exclusively locks every table when a write transaction first accesses it, so in practice transactions can only be concurrent access if it's to different parts of the DB. Nobody wants to use such a database in situations where concurrency is desirable or useful.

All real world implementations are compromises.

### `READ COMMITTED` default

PostgreSQL's default is [`READ COMMITTED` isolation, a well-defined isolation level that *permits* non-repeatable and phantom reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_committed), as [discussed in the PostgreSQL manual on transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

### `SERIALIZABLE` isolation

You can request stricter [`SERIALIZABLE` isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Serializable) on a per-transaction basis or as a per-user, per-database or (not recommended) global default. This provides much stronger guarantees, though still not perfect, at the cost of forcibly rolling back transactions if they interact in ways that couldn't happen if they had run serially.

Because your concurrent queries will always try to grab the first job, no matter how many jobs there are, all but one will abort with serialization failures. So in practice you don't get any useful concurrency and might as well have a single connection handing out jobs to workers.

(Note that prior to PostgreSQL 9.1 `SERIALIZABLE` offered much weaker guarantees and would not detect quite a lot of cases where transactions were interdependent.)

### Auto-re-run `SERIALIZABLE`

PostgreSQL does *not* auto-re-run `SERIALIZABLE` transactions that abort due to serialization failures. There are cases where this would be quite useful, but other cases where doing so would be completely wrong and dangerous - especially where read/modify/write cycles via the application are involved. At this time there is no support for automatically rerunning transactions on serialization failures. The application is expected to retry.

### Don't write a DIY queuing system

It looks like what you're trying to do is write a queuing system. Consider not doing that. Writing a robust, reliable and correct queueing system is hard, and there are a few good ones already available that you could adopt. You have to handle things like crash-safety, what happens when someone takes a task then fails to complete it, race conditions around completion just as you give up on the task handler completing it, etc. There are lots of subtle concurrency problems. Don't try to DIY.

### 9.5 and `SKIP LOCKED`

PostgreSQL 9.5, still in development, adds a feature that makes queuing quite a bit easier.

It lets you say that if when you `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, if a row is locked, you should ignore it and carry on to find the next not-locked row. This is very useful when combined with a `LIMIT` as it makes it possible to say "find me the first row someone else isn't already trying to claim". So it becomes very simple to write queuing that grabs jobs safely and concurrently.

Until that feature is available I strongly suggest that you stick to single connection queue management, or use a well-tested task queue system.

Comment: excellent answer. You do not happen to know, whether it is possible to tell postgres to automatically restart a query in case of a dirty read?

Comment: @arthur Dirty reads aren't possible due to snapshots. So there's no dirty read to restart after. If you mean phantom reads, then no, as I explained above in auto-re-run.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from craig-ringer fully answers the question. For the sake of completeness, I add up the following trivial code to solve the issue using locks:

```
create or replace function f_requestJob(
    jobs           text, 
    jobs_running   text, 
    jobs_completed text
) 
    returns bigint as
$$
declare 
    sql varchar;
    c bigint;

begin
    execute 'LOCK TABLE ' || jobs           || ' IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE'; 
    execute 'LOCK TABLE ' || jobs_running   || ' IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE'; 
    execute 'LOCK TABLE ' || jobs_completed || ' IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE';

    sql := '
    insert into ' || jobs_running || '
    select x.fid     
    from ( 
      SELECT fid FROM ' || jobs || '
      except 
      select fid from ' || jobs_running || '
      except 
      select fid from ' || jobs_completed || '
     ) as x limit 1
    returning(fid)';

    execute sql into c;

    return c; --may be a null value

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```